# How to search for a word in a string and highlight word in a text view in android?

Tags: android, textview

in my android application i have a string that contains a specific word so i want to display whole string in text view and the specific word should be highlighted.Hope following image will give you an idea.

[image]

I have used following code to do this but its not working.

CODE:

con is my string and groupNameContent is the text field.

```
con.replaceAll(arrGroupelements[groupPosition][5],"<font color='#CA278C'>"+arrGroupelements[groupPosition][5]+"</font>.");
groupNameContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(con));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for each word, you can use:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
//use a loop to change text color
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("partial colored text");        
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 2, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Comment: it's easy, for each word you want to highlight, you put start index and end index in setSpan method. You can have an array of strings and highlight each word in a loop or make your text an array of words and decide if each word must be highlighted.

Comment: yep it is highlighting.if please can you give me a way to find out   start index and end index of a word.(i mean logic inside the loop).

Comment: for(String word : words){
int start = test.inxexOf(word);
int end = start + word.length();
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(bigText);        
    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(WordtoSpan);

Comment: Hello guys , can you please @BudaGavril, try to show me how you turned a TextView into a an Array and you used **words**, in the  for loop

Comment: Coz me i was doing it like this in the searchView , but all the words become Invisible nad only the searched text is the one which appears

Answer (score 5):

If I can understand you have the list of words and you want to find this words in text and highlight them so in this answer you have three input parameter:

1. full text.
2. yourList
3. yourTextview to show the result text

   ```
   String text = "full of your text";
   Spannable textSpannable = new SpannableString(text);

   for (int j =0 ; j<yourList.size() ; j++) {
       //word of your list
       String word = String.valueOf(yourList.get(j));
       //find index of words
       for (int i = -1; (i = text.indexOf(word, i + 1)) != -1; i++) {
           //find the length of word for set color
           int last = i + word.length();
           //set text color with spannable
           textSpannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#0cab8f")),
                   i, last, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       }
   }
   yourTextView.setText(textSpannable);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

**Just to make it simple, here I post my methode**

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

**First getting ready to use the methode**

```
    ArrayList<String> searchWords = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Second", "Scottish", "forces", "England"));

    String text = "1333 – Second War of Scottish Independence: The Scottish-held town of Berwick-upon-Tweed surrendered to English forces, ending a siege led by Edward III of England (depicted).";


    TextView sampleTextView = new TextView(currentContext); // currentContext = getContext();

    if (searchWords != null) {
        Spannable newText = setSpanHighlight(text, searchWords);
        sampleTextView.setText(newText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
    else{
        sampleTextView.setText(text);
    }
```

**The methode**

```
    private Spannable setSpanHighlight(String text, @NonNull ArrayList<String> searchWord) {
    Spannable newText = new SpannableString(text);

    if (searchWord.size() != 0) {
        for (String word : searchWord){
            if (text.contains(word)){
                int beginIndex = text.indexOf(String.valueOf(word)); //Unnecessary 'String.valueOf()' call => if you have something else than String
                int endIndex = beginIndex + word.length();

                newText.setSpan(
                        new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),
                        beginIndex,
                        endIndex,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }
    return newText;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post signature links, or links to random comment. They may be seen by the community as spam

Comment: what should I do if I want to put the source site there?

Comment: If you want to link *directly* to a source, you can do so. Linking to a mere domain looks like spam. If you do link to a site you are affiliated with, please be sure to follow the rules for [promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: "link directly to a source" does that mean I have to write the whole Link in answer?

Comment: As in link to the specific page that has the code or comments you're posting