# How to mark words in TextView

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I have a .txt file inside my assets folder that has a massive HTML in it...

I call it to a string, remove some HTML tags using JSoup Library, and set this string as a TextView's text:

```
InputStream is;
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
String html;

try {
    is = getAssets().open("html.txt");
    html = convertStreamToString(is);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
for (Element link : links) {
    doc.select("a").unwrap();
}

doc.select("title").remove();

tv.setText(fromHtml(html));
```

It results in a TextView showing a really big and beautiful formatted HTML code

When the user touches any word in that TextView, I want to change the word's background color, marking it, and storing that mark to be marked again when user restart the application... How could I achieve that?

**EDIT:**

Also, how could I work with `Spannable` and `Html.fromHtml()` together?

Answer (score 0):

1. This post can help you get the index of your word. 
   [OnClick Position in String in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285682/onclick-position-in-string-in-textview). Save the start index of word.
2. From the index to end of word, use spannablestring to highlight the word. [How to search for a word in a string and highlight word in a text view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279632/how-to-search-for-a-word-in-a-string-and-highlight-word-in-a-text-view-in-androi/10279703#10279703)
3. When you load the text again, you can do the same for the stored index of word.

Comment: Using that examples, I would have to use `Spannable.setSpan()` before setting the string as a TextView's text, right? But to `setSpan()`, I already have to know the index of the clicked word, don't I? How could I make the string, and then, use `setSpan()` to every word of the string?