# TextView Bold the second line

Tags: android, textview

I don't know if that's possibole or not, but i'm trying to achieve some thing like this :

[image]

Second line is bold, what  i already done :

[image]

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Check-in Date \n 10-08-2017"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_calendar"
        android:textColor="@color/hintColor"
        android:drawablePadding="2dp"
        android:transitionName="price"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textInfoSmall" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use two textviews or you can use

```
Textview tvcheckIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkIn);
tvcheckIn.setText( Html.fromHtml("First Line<br><b>Second Line"));
```

Comment: well, i will try your solution, i think it's useful for my case.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way is to Use two TextViews

Or try SpannableString as explained here

[How to make part of the text Bold in android at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979821/how-to-make-part-of-the-text-bold-in-android-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

I think the better practice is separate it into two TextView wrapped inside an Layout.

Because the texts "Check-in Date" and "Check-out Date" is always static. So use separate TextView will reduce String concatenate (Eg: `textView.setText("Check-in Date \n" + checkInDate);`), and make the source easier to read and extend.

If you still want to highlight part of text in TextView, there is already an answered question here: [Android - Highlight a Word In a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843596/android-highlight-a-word-in-a-textview).
This is all about `SpannableString`.