# Highlight filtered text in RecyclerView when using SearchView widget AndroidX

Tags: java, android

I'm using SearchView widget in my app and it works fine but I'm trying to highlight the text color of the search results and can't seem to do it.

i.e: RecyclerView item has the following text "Hey there"
When a user searches for "Hey" then the color of this keyword should change.

Here's my filter code from the adapter:

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String query = constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : null;

                // ----

                if (query != null && !query.isEmpty()) {
                    ArrayList<TextTypingObject> newFilteredTextTypingObjectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (TextTypingObject textTypingObject : mTextTypingObjectList) {
                        if (textTypingObject.getTextTyping().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(query.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()))) {
                            newFilteredTextTypingObjectArrayList.add(textTypingObject);
                        }
                    }

                    // ----

                    mTextTypingObjectFilteredList = newFilteredTextTypingObjectArrayList;
                } else {
                    mTextTypingObjectFilteredList = mTextTypingObjectList;
                }

                // ----

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mTextTypingObjectFilteredList;
                filterResults.count = mTextTypingObjectFilteredList.size();

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
                /*if (filterResults.count == 0) {
                    // There is no "notifyDataSetInvalidated()" method in RecyclerView.Adapter
                } else {*/
                mTextTypingObjectFilteredList = (ArrayList<TextTypingObject>) filterResults.values;

                // ----

                notifyDataSetChanged();
                /*}*/
            }
        };
    }
```

SearchView from the fragment:

```
                        if (mSearchView != null) {
                            mSearchView.setQuery(null, true);
                            mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                                    Filter filter = mTextTypingCustomAdapter.getFilter();

                                    if (filter != null) {
                                        filter.filter(s);

                                        // ----

                                        mSearchView.clearFocus();

                                        // ----

                                        return true;
                                    }

                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                                    Filter filter = mTextTypingCustomAdapter.getFilter();

                                    if (filter != null) {
                                        filter.filter(s);

                                        return true;
                                    }

                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            mSearchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mSearchView.clearFocus();
                        }
```

Comment: Can you specify the problem?

Comment: @PedroAGSantos search is working fine but just want to change the color of query text, like highlight it with the accent color.

Comment: then did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843596/android-highlight-a-word-in-a-textview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Highlight a Word In a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843596/android-highlight-a-word-in-a-textview)